# React MUI Drawer overlaying page content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'd like to have a Drawer that doesn't overlay the page content. So far I have the following code

```
  <ThemeProvider theme={oclockTheme}>
        <main>
            <Drawer
                variant='temporary'
                open={showMenu}
                hideBackdrop
            >
                <List>
                    <ListItem sx={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <img src={oclockLogo} alt="O'Clock logo" />
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
                
                <Divider light />
                
                <List >
                    <ListItem>
                       Menu item
                    </ListItem>

                </List>
            </Drawer>
            
            <Button onClick={() => setShowMenu(true)} variant="contained" color="primary">Teste</Button>
        </main>
    </ThemeProvider >
```

And the problem is that the Drawer overlays my button

[image: Drawer closed]

[image: Drawer opened]

And I'd like to push my bottom to the right when the Drawer is opened and pull it back to the left when it's closed...

I've seen a solution in the library docs, but I'd like to know if anyone else can help me doing it with a cleaner/smaller code. I also know that we have the SwipeableDrawer, but I couldn't find a way to change its styles...

Answer (score 1):

Use [persistent drawer](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer) instead.

[image: Edit beautiful-kalam-h4sdi]